# How to update more than 1000 records in SQL Server by LOOP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I need to update more than 1000 records. The values are in another table.

I tried with this query:

```
Update tblEnrollment
SET TrOOPCurrentYrBalanceAmt = tr.TrOOPCurrentYrBalanceAmt
from tblTrOOPbalance tr
join tblMember mem on tr.MedicareNumber = mem.MANumber
join tblEnrollment enr on mem.MemberID = enr.MemberID
where enr.EnrollmentID IN ('16823', '16828')
```

but I get an error :

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tblEnrollment_UpdateTrigger, Line 9
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value.
>   This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I guess I can't update more than 1 with the query. How can I update multiple records?

Thanks,

Because the table tblenrollment has a trigger that prevents updating multiple records, I have to use LOOP to update a record one by one.
Could anyone help how to write LOOP query please?

Comment: Do you have other code in procedure tblEnrollment_UpdateTrigger?

Comment: Your `update` statement has no subquery, so it is not generating that error.

Comment: Please post your all Code of SQL Query. So that we can provide you exact answer. as @GordonLinoff said, the above query should work correct because it does not have any sub-query to return Data.

Comment: I had no idea about tblEnrollment_UpdateTrigger caused the error.  I searched it in the DB and found that it is a trigger..  I don't even know what trigger is...   Anyway I am going to dig some more and see what I can find out and I will update.   Thanks for the helps!

Comment: Here is what I found out:  The trigger in the table (tblEnrollment) prevents updating more than one record.   I think I should use either loop or cursor.   I have to figure out how to use those.

Comment: Classic mistake in writing triggers.

Answer (score 2):

Of cource, you can update multiple records!!! 
It seems that you have other code in your procedure `tblEnrollment_UpdateTrigger` and there is a problem with subquery. Please check if you do not have similar cases where sabquery will be return more than 1 record:

- `where column = (select column2 from table)`
- `update tab set column = (select column2 from table)`
- `select @variable = (select column2 from table)`

About `UPDATE` statement, I think will be better use something like that:

```
update enr
set    enr.TrOOPCurrentYrBalanceAmt = tr.TrOOPCurrentYrBalanceAmt
from   tblEnrollment enr
join   tblMember mem on enr.MemberID = mem.MemberID
join   tblTrOOPbalance tr on mem.MANumber = tr.MedicareNumber 
where  enr.EnrollmentID in ('16823','16828')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this `update` is better. Does tblEnrollment have a primary key or unique column?

```
update tblEnrollment
set TrOOPCurrentYrBalanceAmt = (
    select tr.TrOOPCurrentYrBalanceAmt
    from tblTrOOPbalance tr
    where tr.MemberID = tblEnrollment.MemberID
)
where EnrollmentID in ('16823', '16828')
```

Here's a hack that might be useful for a one-time fix:

```
declare @done bit = 0;
while @done = 0 begin

update top(1) tblEnrollment
set TrOOPCurrentYrBalanceAmt = (
    select tr.TrOOPCurrentYrBalanceAmt
    from tblTrOOPbalance tr
    where tr.MemberID = tblEnrollment.MemberID
)
where EnrollmentID in ('16823', '16828')
    and coalesce(TrOOPCurrentYrBalanceAmt, -999999) <>
        coalesce((
            select tr.TrOOPCurrentYrBalanceAmt
            from tblTrOOPbalance tr
            where tr.MemberID = tblEnrollment.MemberID
        ), -999999);

set @done = case when @@rowcount = 0 then 1 else 0 end
end
```

You can inspect and debug with this:

```
select
    TrOOPCurrentYrBalanceAmt as TrOOPCurrentYrBalanceAmt1,
    (
        select tr.TrOOPCurrentYrBalanceAmt
        from tblTrOOPbalance tr
        where tr.MemberID = tblEnrollment.MemberID
    ) as TrOOPCurrentYrBalanceAmt2
from tblEnrollment
where EnrollmentID in ('16823', '16828')
    and coalesce(TrOOPCurrentYrBalanceAmt, -999999) <>
        coalesce((
            select tr.TrOOPCurrentYrBalanceAmt
            from tblTrOOPbalance tr
            where tr.MemberID = tblEnrollment.MemberID
        ), -999999);
```

Comment: Thanks for the post @shawnt00.   As I added in the question, the tblenrollment table has a trigger that prevents update multiple records. I used your query but got the same error.    I'd like to use LOOP to update one by one.   EnrollmentId is a primary key.

Comment: I understand the problem with the trigger and I recognize that the `update` still won't work by itself. But I used that form of the update inside the loop at the end of my answer. Is that the one that errored?

Comment: If `EnrollmentId` is the primary key then I think you should be able to run the first script twice (with a different ID each time.)

Comment: This works!   thanks shawnt00.    One question remains is that when I update with your query.  The null values in tblEnrollment are not updated.    why is that?   thanks!

Comment: I thought I handled nulls with the coalesces. You could certain just say `and TrOOPCurrentYrBalanceAmt is not null` if those are the precisely the rows you need to supply values for. You might also need to make sure you actually have a value to returned by those subqueries.

Comment: that doesn't work.....   :(      the null values in the tblEnrollment are not updated with the values from tblTrOOPbalance

Comment: Actually I meant to write `is null` above.